# RAID - install on an existing system

Tags: raid

I have a running system, BIOS is set AHCI, no raid drives.

In this system I have two 4TB storage only drives, no OS, and they run independent.

I would like to mirror these two 4TB drives.  RAID 1

a. Will Windows freak out if I change the BIOS SATA controller to RAID ?

b. If I can get Windows to accept that change, can I then use the BIOS to setup those two storage drives to be RAID 1 without destroying the Windows install being on a different physical drive ?

Comment: “Will Windows freak out if I change the BIOS SATA controller to RAID?” - Yes; RAID mode is only if you will be using the RAID as your system disk.

Comment: Just use windows dynamic disks and setup RAID in Windows. This won’t require a change to your BIOS settings. It will, in any case, require wiping the data drives.

Comment: I've done that, and it works [sort of], but ALWAYS resyncing.  Also, I'm dual booting Linux and use that OS much more than Windows.  I'm really looking for a hardware solution.